# How to compute monthly interval average and group by month

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm using Postgres.

I have the following query, which computes an average time interval for each day of month. Well, at least each day where I have data available :

```
SELECT 
  date_part('year'::text, c.date) AS yyyy,
  to_char(c.date, 'MM'::text) AS monthnumber,
  to_char(c.date, 'TMMonth'::text) AS monthname,
  c.date,
  l.name AS lineName,
  avg(COALESCE(c.observed_arrival_time,  v.arrival_time) - v.arrival_time) AS time_difference


FROM Counter c
  JOIN vehicule_journey_at_stop v ON v.id = c.vj_at_stop_id
  JOIN vehicule_journey vv ON vv.id = v.vehicule_journey_id
  JOIN route_analyse r ON r.id = vv.route_id
  JOIN line l ON l.id = r.line_id
  JOIN pt_network n ON n.id = l.network_id

WHERE 
  date_part('year',c.date) = 2014
  AND c.name = 'montée'

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1,2
```

I get mostly what I want, results look like this :

```
...
2014;"07";"Juillet";"2014-07-12";"Ligne 01";"00:04:16.0685"
2014;"07";"Juillet";"2014-07-20";"Ligne 01";"00:04:56.509875"
2014;"07";"Juillet";"2014-07-23";"Ligne 02";"00:00:00"
2014;"07";"Juillet";"2014-07-24";"Ligne 03";"00:00:00"
...
```

Important thing is the average time in last position, computed for each "line" (eg. "Ligne 01" or Ligne "02").

Thing is, I would like to have those results grouped by month, with an average of intervals for each days of month available, i.e. :

```
...
2014;"07";"Juillet";"Ligne 01";"00:04:36.5974375"
2014;"07";"Juillet";"Ligne 02";"00:00:00"
2014;"07";"Juillet";"Ligne 03";"00:00:00"
...
```

But I can't get it to work.
If I remove the `c.date` from the select (which cause my data not to be grouped by month but by day, I get that), I get false average values.

Comment: removing `c.date` from the field list and from group by clause too should do it, what do you mean false average values?

Comment: I mean that... I'm stupid. My computation was false from the beginning, average computed value is indeed the good one when I remove the c.date from the select. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-write "group by" using actual field names, not just numbers, and remove c.date from select afterwards. That's easy.

Comment: Yeah that's probably easy for you. If I'm asking the question, it's certainly not for me ! I made a mistake while verifying results, my request was correct. Thank you anyway.